# Gravity form save and continue function

Tags: wordpress

1. I want to generate new Auth token each time a save and continue button is clicked, because I work with a multi page form and when a user clicks the save and continue a token is generated or a link with token is generated, but that one token is used to complete the entire form even if the user click on save and continue many times and in different page section of the form. 
   But what i want is one brand new token or link url generated every time the save and continue is clicked, not one generated token for any entry.
2. I want the generated url or token or code to redirect to next page of the multi page form instead of showing the already filled page in the form, I want the new token or code to open the next page that is unfilled.